# swift-package does not exist on my toolchain

Tags: swift

I am following some tutorials, basically trying to start an echo server in swift, without xcode, just command line and plain text editors, so I can get a grasp of the ecosystem
but I found this error for which there seems to be no solution already online

```
swift package init --type executable

error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.14.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-package (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was pointing to the Swift compiler in the OS toolchain (which doesn't have swiftpm)

So after running

```
export TOOLCHAINS=default swift package init --type executable
```

The command worked successfully